# Get a string from an object in the template

Tags: scala, templates, playframework, twirl

Imagine I have a case class like so:

```
   case class Team(_id: Option[BSONObjectID], name: String = "", city: String = "", country: String = "")
```

And am passing this into my template (in Play 2.5/Scala/reactiveMongo 0.11.14) like this:

```
   @(teams : Seq[models.Team])

   ...

      @for(team <- teams){
            <tr>
                <td>@team._id</td>
                <td>@team.name</td>
                <td>@team.city</td>
                <td>@team.country</td>
            </tr>
      }

   ...
```

I need to get `@team._id` (which is currently type `Option[BSONObjectID]`) to a `string` - so just the `BSONObjectID` characters as a `string`. I have been trying to declare *reusable values* as documented [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates#declaring-reusable-values) but I can't seem to get it right. Ordinarily I would use `flatMap` but this isn't working as expected within the template. Thanks for any help!

---

Following on from this it now seems that I should use a method within the case case class as @marcospereira suggested. However I am a little stuck (unsurprisingly!) on the syntax in a regex expression. So I am trying to make a string like this - `BSONObjectID("59654f33b17946eac2323b3e")` be just `59654f33b17946eac2323b3e`. This is what I have:

```
def idAsString = _id.flatMap(bson => """\".*?(")""".r.findFirstIn(bson.toString)).getOrElse("")
```

But this also returns the quotation marks, e.g. `"59654f33b17946eac2323b3e"`. As mentioned I don't want those - thanks to anyone that can help with this as I can't quite get the syntax right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so this is the total answer (at least for me).

Getting `@team._id` (which is currently type `Option[BSONObjectID]`) to a `string` is done by adding a method which does this (as suggested by @marcospereira [upvote]) to the case class. But I was still having issues as to how to do this, e.g. using `regex`, `.split`, etc. This is what I believe is the simplest way:

```
   case class Team(_id: Option[BSONObjectID] = None, name: String = "", city: String = "", country: String = "") {

       def idAsString = _id.map(_.stringify).getOrElse("")

   }
```

So now I can call this method within the template to convert the `Option[BSONObjectID]` to the `string` like this:

```
   @(teams : Seq[models.Team])

   ...

      @for(team <- teams){
            <tr>
                <td>@team.idAsString</td>
                <td>@team.name</td>
                <td>@team.city</td>
                <td>@team.country</td>
            </tr>
      }

   ...
```

Always seems obvious afterwards!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
case class Team(_id: Option[BSONObjectID] = None, name: String = "", city: String = "", country: String = "") {

    def idAsString(): String = _id.getOrElse("")

}
```

And then:

```
<td>@team.idAsString()</td>
```

Notice that I've add `None` as default for `_id`. You can also have a "view helper" like this:

```
package helpers

object OptionViewHelpers {
  def optionValueToString(o: Option[_]): String = o match {
    case Some(v) => String.valueOf(v)
    case _ => ""
  }
}
```

And your view:

```
@import helpers._

<td>@{OptionViewHelpers.optionValueToString(team._id)}</td>
```

The advantage here is that you can reuse it in other scenarios.

Comment: Thanks. Of course this returns a string such as `BSONObjectID("59654f33b17946eac2323b3e")` but I am looking for the just the `59654f33b17946eac2323b3e` part. so I am now altering the `idAsString()` method. I will now edit my original question as I think that `BSONObjectID` cannot be mapped on (which is why `flatMap` doesn't work) and therefore we do need to convert to a `string` and then get a portion of that string - which is a shame.

Comment: Your methodology in the first part was correct so I upvoted - thanks!